# ?taxonomy_name=slug shows both posts and pages

Tags: taxonomy

Visiting

`mysite.com/?taxonomy_name=slug`,

or otherwise querying for a taxonomy, lists both matching posts *and* pages.  (My taxonomy applies to both posts and pages.)  I would prefer that it listed only the posts.  I don't think earlier version of wordpress worked this way.

Am I doing something wrong?  Is there a proper way to get just the posts?  I can think of hacks to fix it such as modifying the archive template or query hooks, but is there a simpler way?  Can this behavior be changed in the way you register your taxonomy?

Answer (score 0):

I think you were trying to use

```
mysite.com/tag/tag_slug
```

ie `damien.co/tag/wordpress`

You can try to use ?s= (search) and ?t= (tag) as URL parameters

Comment: Well, my question is not about the specific URL or query syntax that you use.  It is just about the output.  tag/tag_slug isn't a good example because tags only apply to posts and never to pages.  But yes in your syntax tax/tax_slug is what I'm asking about.  If the tax applies to posts and pages, is it always true that both will show up in this query?

Comment: hi again - categories and tags by default are not assigned to pages. if they were added, then this is part of your theme customisation and the theme author would have decided to include page-tags (same applies to adding tags or categories to custom post formats). hope that helps? Damien